# Emailing All Users Who Commented On A Discussion Topic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I spent hours on this and I just cannot get it:

What I am trying to do is; email all users who have made a comment on a discussion board whenever a new comment is posted.

I am using **user_mailer.rb**

```
def new_post_from_buyer(post)
  @post = post
  users = User.all.posts.where(:project_id => post.project.id)
  mail(:to        => 'support@freelancify.com',
       :bcc       => #Somehow turn the users variable i just named into an array of their emails
       :subject   => 'The Project Poster Posted A New Comment')
end
```

I have the UserMailer.new_post_from_buyer(@post).deliver correctly placed in the posts_controller.rb

So there's a few things that has to happen which I cannot for the life of me get to work successfully.

1 - I have to get all the Users who's Posts match the current Project. (to clarify, a Project contains a discussion board in which where all the posts go) The current code in the mailer throws a undefined method for 'posts', and every other way I tried won't work.

2 - I then have to take those Users and extract their emails (which is a column in the Users table)

3 - I need to then be able to take all their emails and turn it into an array separated by commas so I can throw it in the :bcc of the user_mailer.rb.

How would you go about getting this to work? A new way with .map or some method I have no idea about, fixing up the code I think I need?

I am running Rails 3.1.

To further clarify:

- User has_many Posts.
- Project has_many Posts.
- Post belongs_to User.
- Post belongs_to Project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the most efficient way to do it, as it is generally better to use database commands to comb data, but based on your models and relationships you could use ruby methods to do something like this:

```
def new_post_from_buyer(post)
  # This assumes that the attribute on the user that holds the email is called 'email'
  array_of_user_emails = post.project.posts.map { |pos| pos.user.email }
  mail(:to        => 'support@freelancify.com',
       :bcc       => array_of_user_emails,
       :subject   => 'The Project Poster Posted A New Comment')
end
```

I think you were also on the right track in your attempt, just with wrong syntax.  This might actually be a little more efficient:

```
def new_post_from_buyer(post)
  # This assumes that the attribute on the user that holds the email is called 'email'
  array_of_user_emails = User.includes(:posts).select(:email).where('posts.project_id = ?', post.project_id).map(&:email)
  mail(:to        => 'support@freelancify.com',
       :bcc       => array_of_user_emails,
       :subject   => 'The Project Poster Posted A New Comment')
end
```

This would probably be even more efficient than my first example since it uses SQL to do the searching for the email.  This would only work if you were using ActiveRecord with a SQL based database.

Comment: Thanks.. I assumed the |pos| pos.user.email  was suppose to include the 't'.  Your solution worked! Thank you..  Curious; when it made an array, did it split each email with a comma?

Comment: @JamesF - It could include the 't' but it doesn't have to.  I actually purposely omitted the 't' in this case because the argument for the method is named `post`, and even though I don't think that there would be within the `map` method (since it is in it's own block), I didn't want to risk any variable name collision.  You could change it to be something like `|a_post|` or even `post` like you suggested to be more clear, I just like to make sure I use different variable names for everything both to avoid name collision and for clarity when reading.

Comment: Also I would recommend experimenting with Ruby's `map` method until you get the hang of it, it is incredibly useful, and will also help you understand how ruby various ruby methods work with `block` statements.  [Here is a link to the docs for the `map` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map).

Comment: @JamesF - You're welcome.  I added another answer that uses pure SQL to do the searching which is probably even more efficient since it uses the database to comb the data.  Good luck!

Comment: you can also use delayed_job gem with the code for performance

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def new_post_from_buyer(post)
  @post = post
  posts = Post.where(:project_id => post.project_id)
  @users = []
  posts.each do |p|
    @users << p.user.email
  end
  mail(:to        => 'support@freelancify.com',
       :bcc       => @users
       :subject   => 'The Project Poster Posted A New Comment')
end
```

That would generate an array of all of the users who have a post for that project.

If you wanted to create a string from that array, I believe you would just need to do `@users.join(',')`

EDIT: Inserted code into the method

Comment: Hi. Where would I implement this? I am not too sure of. What would I put in the :bcc area? And I would need to close the 'do', right?

Comment: @JamesF Just edited it to include it inside the method. And yep, I forgot to close the loop

Comment: hey Bwalks, thank you for the answer. I decided to use the .map answer as I need to personally work on it. I still repped you up.